# Dart list gives result separately

Tags: list, flutter, dart

When performing a calculation inside a list , it returns the results as separate list for every calculation.

```
List<int> amountCustom = [
  json.price *
      (cart.toSet().toList().map((value) {
        return [
          value,
          cart.where((element) => element == value).toList().length
        ];
      }).toList()[i][1]),
];
```

what this does is this calculates the item price with the number of repetation and shows the result.

This above code returns this result:

```
    I/flutter (13940): [28]
    I/flutter (13940): [88]
    I/flutter (13940): [1365]
```

But the  problem is it performs and returns the numbers separately which dosen't let me add them up.

What I want is like this: **List = [28,88,1365]**  all in a single list, so I could perform

```
List.reduce((a,b)=> a+b);
```

and obtain a result of **1481**

Comment: Where does `i` come from?

Comment: its just a for loop

Comment: Why don't you fill your list  (or better, compute the sum) in the for loop?

Comment: I guess that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sum = cart
    .toSet()
    .toList()
    .map((value) {
      return [value, cart.where((element) => element == value).toList().length];
    })
    .map((e) => json.price * e[1])
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Comment: Thank yo for the answer but this didnot solve the issue , the result I am getting with your code is  I/flutter (16236): 112
I/flutter (16236): 352
I/flutter (16236): 3640 , all differently as earlier.

Comment: @basudevnayak How are you getting your result? Can you include the code for that?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28039459)

Comment: @MaximMasiutin How come? This was a legit answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "reduce" the outer list by merging all items inside the outer list. You can do this by the following:

```dart
var cart = [[23,45,56],[12],[78,89]];

var items = cart.reduce((a, b)=>a..addAll(b))
```

You can then "reduce" that list to get the final sum:

```dart
var sum = items.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
```

Short hand for the above is:

```dart
cart.reduce((a, b)=>a..addAll(b)).reduce((a,b)=> a+b);
```

Comment: please go through my question again , the proble I am facing is I am gettting the list value all separately, I can apply the .reduce only when all the integers are in same list.

Comment: Please check the edit. If correct the question title and description needs to be edited. Because it is not clear what you are asking for.